# Where is the ASP.NET unhandled exception log in IIS 7?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-7, logging

I've been working in IIS 7 for over a year and I've never been able to find the logs of unhandled ASP.NET exceptions.

In IIS 6, it was `Computer Management`>`System Tools`>`Event Viewer`>`Application`. Where is it in IIS 7?

**UPDATE** Here is the list I get in event viewer. Most are empty and the rest do not contain any ASP.NET errors. After some digging I saw in the `Microsoft` folder there was `Windows` > `Application Server-Applications`. Inside that was `Admin` and `Operational` but these both indicated that they were disabled. Are these the logs I am looking for? If I enable them, will they start logging ASP.NET unhandled exceptions?

> [image: IIS 7 Event Viewer screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should still be in the Application event log, I think?

If you're asking about the location of that log through the GUI:
Eventvwr.exe
or
Server Manager -> Diagnostics -> Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application

Comment: I updated my question so I could post a screenshot of my event viewer and what I see there.

Comment: "Windows Logs" is the bit you're looking for.